# Asymptotic normality of penalized MLE?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, regularization, asymptotics

Let $L(\theta;X)$ denote the log-likelihood of a model and I maximize the following to estimate $\theta$,

$$
\arg\max_{\theta}L(\theta;X)+\lambda\theta^2
$$

If $\lambda$ is 0, then the asymptotic distribution of $\theta$ is normal under suitable regularity conditions. What is the case when $\lambda$ isn't zero? I think there is a Bayesian interpretation of penalization, but I am looking for arguments without invoking any prior distribution.